# Red Berry ID Assistance

Tags: identification, strawberries

This berry has shot up in our strawberry patch - not sure what it is

Anyone have any ideas

Cheers 
Chris

[image]

Comment: What part of the world are you in?

Answer (score 4):

I think it is [Duchesnea indica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_strawberry), also known as Potentilla indica, very invasive. It propagates itself by stolons, so try to take the whole roots out if you don't intend to use the chemical approach.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit confusing - the fruit and leaves strongly suggest Duchesnea indica, but that plant has yellow flowers, and I'm seeing white flowers in the picture. On close inspection, there seem to be at least two stems with thorns - if the white flowers are appearing on those, then you likely have another invader mixed in there, possibly a blackberry. If the white flowers go on to produce similar red fruits to that already present, the plant may actually be a [wild strawberry (Fragaria virginiana).](http://www.illinoiswildflowers.info/prairie/plantx/wld_strawberryx.htm)

Comment: Eagle for spotting the stems with thorns, although they are not in great focus and the leaves seem to be very consistent across the photo, so not convinced *Rubus* is in there, and the fruit definitely isn't *Rubus*. It's a bit out of focus down there. I am pretty certain that the fruit is *Duchesnea*. OP should taste it - *Fragaria* will taste a lot better than *Duchesnea* which will be pretty nothing-ish (some say watermelon, which I kind of get, but not worth eating really).

Comment: @Georgeofalltrades whatever those thorny stems belong to, they're neither Fragaria nor  Duchesna... likeliest explanation is Duchesna with a random blackberry or raspberry  or something with white flowers starting to grow too...

Comment: @bamboo Took a closer look today those white flowers have turned into more of the similar red berries . Would this mean its Fragaria virginiana

Comment: The photograph seems to be the same one posted earlier so still not sure, but I don't really think it is Fragaria either... have you another photo you forgot to post, showing more progress with the forming berries? And are all the stems thorny on this plant, because I can't tell that either? Also, can you pull off the ripe fruit at the top - how it comes off the stem will indicate if its raspberry or strawberry

Answer (score 2):

Given that Duchesnea indica rarely ever grows above 6", I think it is completely safe to assume that is not it.  Not to mention, I don't see a single leaf that would make me think it is D. indica.  The only plant I see in this picture is Rubus spp.  The white flower, the thorny stem, the intact sepals all are just screaming raspberry.  Even the beautiful ripe raspberry is screaming raspberry.  It's a raspberry.  =]

Comment: It definitely looks related to a raspberry, to me. Maybe Rubus probus.